# File type missed after share with ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-studio

I used this code to share an image from app but mime type is unknown and its just a file, for example in dropbox it share right file with name "sample_image" instead of "sample_image.jpg".

```
Uri image_uri=Uri.parse("android.resource/"+getPackageName()+"/drawable/sample_image");
Intent share=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,image_uri);
share.setType("image/*");
startActivity(share);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imgUrl));
startActivity(shareIntent);
```